# rename multiple file in a directory in unix

Tags: unix

I have a directory which contains multiple files with names like this:

```
filename.ch.txt.
```

I want to change all the file names to something like this.

```
filename_ch.txt
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do it in unix...? I tried rename command but it didn't work.

This is what I did (escaping "." and "_" characters):

```
shell> rename 's/\\.ch/\\_ch/' *.txt
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do:

Here I mock your files:

```
touch {1..30}.ch.txt.
```

Then you rename them this way:

```
for i in `ls`; do dest="${i%.ch.txt.}_ch.txt"; mv ${i} ${dest}; done
```

Comment: Is this what you needed? If yes please vote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape only metacharacters the "." is one so putting a '\' before "." escapes it but do not escape "_". This is what you need to do

> rename 's/\.ch/_ch/' *.txt.

Comment: is your file name "filename_ch.txt." ? If yes then replace "\*.txt" with "\*.txt."

Comment: file name is filename.ch.txt and I want to replace it with filename_ch.txt.